# Does Angular Build Unused Components From Third Party Angular Modules

Tags: angular, build

There is a component library which contains 100 s of components inside a angular module. Consider, if someone using that library to build a own application and only imports component 1, 2 and 3.

When that app is built using `nb build` does all 100 component inside the module gets compiled or only component 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is depend on build options that used when building the angular application. By default when using

`ng build --prod`

to build the angular cli will compile all 100(n) components and bundled into the application. But when using

`ng build --prod --build-optimizer`

The unused components will be discarted. So Only 1,2 and 3 components are compiled and built. However this may introduce some bugs.

When using `--build-optimizer` option there is a process three shaking on webpack is happening (Tree shaking is a term commonly used in the JavaScript context for dead-code elimination). Following Articles were helpful when solving this problem,

- [Web pack three shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)
- [The Build Optimizer DevKit Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the declarations array of the module file. Only the components added in declarations array of the module file, will be included in the build generated by angular-cli.

Comment: Do have any source to confirm that?

Comment: I tried it some times and tested this again before answering. You can too. Create a component in your app and define a string in its ts file. Initialize it with a unique text e.g. 'i love coding'. Remove this component from declarations of module and build the project. After the build, try finding that text in main bundle js and all the chunks bundle js files(in case of lazy loading) of the build. You wont find it. Now add the component in declarations of module and build again. You will find that text in either main or chunk bundles js after building again. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Nabil, Wow that's cleaver. But what about an external module. By that we can guess that a component won't be complied. But what about a module, you know since each module will import all component inside to export when writing a external component library

Comment: For external modules, all components in the declaration of imported module are compiled for current module even if that component is not in exports.

Comment: Yeah exactly, Please see my answer

Comment: Here is an article how to create a own npm module, so it is required to import and export each component when publishing a new component [link](https://codeburst.io/how-to-built-npm-ready-component-library-with-angular-a812a22dc1d5)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help